# Flutter - Pick files and get their path or URI

Tags: flutter, filepath, filepicker

With [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), I can't get file's real path or URI from `FilePicker.platform.pickFiles()`. It only returned something like this

> /data/user/0/***my_app_dir***/cache/file_picker/***file***

and logged this

> I/FilePickerUtils(27005): Caching from URI: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1519
>
> D/FilePickerUtils(27005): File loaded and cached
> at:/data/user/0/***my_app_dir***/cache/file_picker/***file***
>
> D/FilePickerDelegate(27005): File path:[com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FileInfo@705d9ef]

That's not what I want. I just want the real original absolute file path, the file information, regardless of what I'll going to do with the file. So I'm looking for a package that do that or the solution how to manually pick file and get the file path like I could do natively. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you cannot do that, no package provides this

Comment: @pskink why...?

Comment: because some files on Android are backed by content providers and they do not provide file path - only data and basic file info

Comment: @pskink but still file_picker managed to get the path. i just need that path. that's all

Comment: yes, it managed, it is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1519` - it is media content provider `Uri` - you cannot know where physically that files is stored

Comment: @pskink so why can't i get a string like that?

Comment: btw check those two: https://commonsware.com/community/t/get-file-from-uri/624 and https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible with native code. It's just package publisher who made it unavailable using it. Follow [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to implement file path picker on native code. It works for me.